# how to use LINQ in entity frame work

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am a beginner in Entity framework , I want to use LINQ in EF. so please guide me from where i should start learn, what is the basic resources for this .

Comment: [LINQ to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386964.aspx)

Comment: -1 This is not a website for you to ask for documentation.

Comment: -1. You can search on net and get lot of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these two links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff628210.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx

The best way to learn is to use them in the real projects

Answer (score 0):

There are basically three ways you can query data in EF:

1. LINQ To Entities - Uses standard LINQ operators; more intuitive
2. Entity SQL - Syntactically similar to TSQL; targets Conceptual Schema directly
3. Query Builder Methods - Uses Extension Methods defined on IEnumerable and IQueryable

LINQ To Entities is the most preferred way followed by Query Builder Methods.

You can start by understanding most common operators used with LINQ To Entities.  Eg., from, join, into, let, group by, order by, select, etc.